How to predict if someone will accept a plea bargain?
Suppose there is a mafia network in some city. One day, the police catches everyone and the court presses charges against them. I tried to make a network below in which each node is a member in the mafia and the edges represent members that are being tried in the same case:

In the first day, everyone is awaiting trial. As time goes on, from awaiting trial - individuals can either go to: found guilty in court, found innocent in court, or accept a plea bargain.
Suppose we have information on each individual, e.g. age, total number of crimes charged with, previous criminal history. Is it possible to make a mathematical model which predicts if someone will be more likely to accept a plea bargain based on their individual information and the court results of their codefendants and the overall court results of the network?
For example, if an individual sees that many of their codefendants (and in general, people in the network) are getting guilty outcomes - perhaps they might feel more pressured to accepting a plea bargain. On the other hand, suppose the court is having a hard time convicting individuals - now, someone might think their chances are better to not accept a plea bargain and try to win the case.
Of course, individuals might also balance this with their personal case details. For example, even though everyone else is going free, an individual with a large criminal history and currently convicted of many crimes might think that there chances are so bad - it is still better to accept a plea bargain.
Are there any mathematical/statistical models that could  be fit to network data of this kind (i.e. can any mathematical models exploit the full network structure of this problem)?

The individual level data would look something like this (assume these variables age ,num_crimes_charged, previous_convictions ,years_in_mafia are static, i.e. never change)
Month = 0
 id age num_crimes_charged previous_convictions years_in_mafia         status time
  1  25                  2                    0              3 Awaiting Trial    0
  2  35                  3                    1              8 Awaiting Trial    0
  3  45                  1                    0             15 Awaiting Trial    0
  4  30                  4                    2              5 Awaiting Trial    0
  5  50                  2                    1             20 Awaiting Trial    0

Month = 1
 id age num_crimes_charged previous_convictions years_in_mafia         status time
  1  25                  2                    0              3         Guilty    1
  2  35                  3                    1              8 Awaiting Trial    1
  3  45                  1                    0             15       Innocent    1
  4  30                  4                    2              5   Plea Bargain    1
  5  50                  2                    1             20 Awaiting Trial    1

Month = 2
 id age num_crimes_charged previous_convictions years_in_mafia       status time
  1  25                  2                    0              3       Guilty    2
  2  35                  3                    1              8       Guilty    2
  3  45                  1                    0             15     Innocent    2
  4  30                  4                    2              5 Plea Bargain    2
  5  50                  2                    1             20 Plea Bargain    2

And the graph component of the data would look something like this (i.e. which individuals are being charged alongside which other individuals - also static, i.e. do not change):
 from to
    1  2
    1  3
    2  4
    3  5
    4  5


Are you a graph theorist working for the mafia? =)

@ Albert: haha , I was trying to think of a scenario to frame my problem .... but nothing came to mind. If we can think of a new example that does not involve mafia but conveys the same complexities, I will gladly change it :) (e.g. ice cream trucks lol)

@Albert: Any ideas on how to start working on this problem?

I don't know how to incorporate the personal details, but I can talk a little about just how one can model what one shall do depending upon information gathered from other defendants in the same case. Would you be interested in just this?

Looking at "epidemic spreading on graphs" might give you some relevant results, although the nodes in your case are not just binary (i.e. they could take the plea bargain, be convicted, be acquitted, or be awaiting trial).

@Yuzuriha Inori: Sorry, just seeing this right now ... sure. thank you so much!

@Varun Vejalla: thank you so much for this ...

One simple approach would be to just make more features that are graph related as inputs to your statistical model. I.e. number of neighbors, %age of neighbors guilty, %age of neighbors tried, avg neighbors years in jail etc. Then use your favorite model to fit the data.
